# Mostrar todos las incidencias relacionadas con un empleado. Consulta MySQL

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

[image: Estoy desarrolando un sistema de incidencias para mi empresa, en el que tengo las sigiuentes tablas y sus relaciones en la siguiente imagen:]

La tabla principal es **incidencias** donde almacena todas las incidencias de los usuarios.
Quiero mostrar las incidencias insertadas por un solo trabajador, para que cuando un **trabajador inicie sesión se muestren solo sus incidencias**.

Si puede servir trabajo con **SESIONES** por si hace falta coger el **_SESSION['user']**

---

He hecho la siguiente consulta pero me muestra una incidencia que coincide con el id de usuario y no esta bien

```js
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

include("conexion.php");

$MySQLConnection = new ConnectionDB();
$MySQL = $MySQLConnection->getDBConnection();
$MySQL->set_charset('utf8');

session_start();

if( $_SESSION['user']){

    $user = $_SESSION['user'];

    $sqlid_user= "SELECT id from usuarios WHERE nombre='$user'";
    $res = $MySQL->query($sqlid_user);

    $iduser=$res->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)["id"]; //convertir array a string

    $sql = "SELECT incidencias.id ,incidencias.titulo, estado.nombre,incidencias.descripcion, incidencias.prevision_cierre, prioridad.nombre, categorias.nombre , usuarios.nombre, usuarios.email
    FROM incidencias
    INNER join prioridad on incidencias.id_prioridad=prioridad.id
    INNER JOIN categorias on incidencias.id_categoria=categorias.id
    INNER JOIN usuarios on incidencias.id_gestor=usuarios.id
    INNER JOIN estado on incidencias.id_estado=estado.id
    WHERE usuarios.id = ".$iduser."";

    $res2 = $MySQL->query($sql);
    $jsonData = array();


    while ($row = $res2->fetch_array()) {
        $jsonData[] = $row;
    }


    echo json_encode($jsonData);
}
```

Comment: Y cual es tu problema. Di que has intentado hacer y muéstralo.

Comment: nose hacer la consulta para mostrarlo

Comment: Inténtalo. Si ni siquiera *sabes* intentarlo, entonces lo primero que necesitas es aprender un poco sobre SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifique un poco el código pero no puedo probarlo.

```
    ini_set('display_errors',1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    include("conexion.php");

    $MySQLConnection = new ConnectionDB();
    $MySQL = $MySQLConnection->getDBConnection();
    $MySQL->set_charset('utf8');



    if( $_SESSION['user']){

        $user = $_SESSION['user'];

        $sqlid_user= "SELECT id from usuarios WHERE nombre='".$user."'";
        $res = $MySQL->query($sqlid_user);

        $iduser=$res->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)["id"]; //convertir array a string

        $sql = "SELECT incidencias.id ,incidencias.titulo, estado.nombre,incidencias.descripcion, incidencias.prevision_cierre, prioridad.nombre, categorias.nombre 
        FROM incidencias
        INNER join prioridad on incidencias.id_prioridad=prioridad.id
        INNER JOIN categorias on incidencias.id_categoria=categorias.id
        INNER JOIN estado on incidencias.id_estado=estado.id
        WHERE id_gestor = ".$iduser."";

        $res2 = $MySQL->query($sql);
        $jsonData = array();


        while ($row = $res2->fetch_array()) {
            $jsonData[] = $row;
        }


        echo json_encode($jsonData);
    }
```